# Multiple borrow in previous iteration of loop

Tags: loops, rust, borrow-checker

Following is the code I'm working on, I explore a directory path with a queue and I want to store the filesystem tree in my data structure (the enum `Entry`):

```
use failure::Error;
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::fs;
use std::io;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let paths = visit_dir(Path::new(".")).map_err(Error::from)?;
    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Entry {
    Dir(PathBuf, Vec<Entry>),
    File(PathBuf),
}

impl Entry {
    fn new_dir(path: &Path) -> Entry {
        Entry::Dir(path.to_path_buf(), Vec::new())
    }

    fn new_file(path: &Path) -> Entry {
        Entry::File(path.to_path_buf())
    }

    /// Append a new Entry to self if self is a directory.
    fn push(&mut self, path: &Path) -> Option<&mut Entry> {
        if let Entry::Dir(_, ref mut content) = self {
            let entry = if path.is_dir() {
                Entry::new_dir(path)
            } else {
                Entry::new_file(path)
            };
            content.push(entry);
            return content.last_mut();
        }
        None
    }

    fn path(&self) -> &Path {
        match self {
            Entry::Dir(path, _) => path,
            Entry::File(path) => path,
        }
    }
}

fn visit_dir(root: &Path) -> io::Result<Entry> {
    let mut dir = Entry::new_dir(root);
    let mut queue = VecDeque::new();
    queue.push_back(&mut dir);

    while !queue.is_empty() {
        let parent = queue.pop_front().unwrap();
        let path = parent.path();
        if path.is_dir() {
            for entry in fs::read_dir(path)? {
                let entry = entry?;
                let path = entry.path();
                let entry = parent.push(&path).unwrap();

                if path.is_dir() {
                    queue.push_back(entry);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Ok(dir)
}
```

Link to [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=edb19d22c36e849bfd2c8b72055a4583)

The error I am getting is:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*parent` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:61:29
   |
61 |                 let entry = parent.push(&path).unwrap();
   |                             ^^^^^^ mutable borrow starts here in previous iteration of loop
```

My questions are:

- Why exactly do I get this error?
- Are there any workaround to solve it?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0e4d069ea460591e8560f22559049fc8, but that very unclear what you are trying to do with your `push` function

Comment: @Stargateur that wouldn't work if I am not mistaken. You are cloning the values, and by doing that the entry that the function returns will not see it's values updated by the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `entry` borrows `parent` mutably in the line:

  ```
  let entry = parent.push(&path).unwrap();
  ```
- Then, you do not release `entry`, because you store it in `queue`. So, `parent` is still borrowed mutably when this is the 2nd iteration in the loop. This is unsafe to do that.

What you are trying to do is a tree of mutable references. That won't work in Rust, and this is generally a bad idea. You should modify the way you want to implement that.

Comment: If I [use recursion](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cf2e1199ad6d1e958d2339ea9f27e261) I can populate the same data structure without any problem. Do you know if there is a better way (especially without recursion) to achieve the same?

Comment: @Nick What is your usecase?

Comment: I need to recreate the filesystem data structure of two directories, to then compare their content.

Comment: Because it may cause stack overflow.

Comment: Did you have a stack overflow? It is hypotetical to hit one.